# Can we have GraphQL response in XML

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I am trying to add a **GraphQL wrapper** on an existing project's REST APIs.
I need to define queries for every existing API. However, a few of them are returning XML responses.

As per my findings, GraphQL's response is always a **valid JSON** ([Link](https://spectrum.chat/graphql/general/graphql-response-in-xml%7Ec9497eb8-075e-4dea-80b9-1442e8ccb8d9))

Is it possible in any way to return the XML response from the GraphQL query?

Comment: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Serialization-Format ... hundreds of graphql clients supporting json ... any for other format? ... serialize to `custom json scalar`? custom xml scalar?

Comment: @xadm can you kindly explain it a bit? I am new to graphQL and having difficulty while understanding how can I return XML?

Comment: simply ... you can't ... graphql is not only a wrapper ... xml response should be converted to json ... but ... all graphql data levels are typed ... you can return a anonymous/unknown structured json node as custom scalar, you can return url to true xml, you can serialize xml to some custom scalar (decode/deserialize on client) ... you should have/been told strict requirements on thjs job